# React Oшибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: reactjs

У меня проблема. Я хочу выводить сразу написанный текст, который написан в `<input>` , в `Col id='output'`. Но у меня выскакивает ошибка при получении `textInput.current.value`.

Задача у меня такая: Хочу когда пользователь заходит на страницу у него спрашивало имя и это имя писалось  в `Col id='output'`. Но как и написал выше есть проблема с `textInput.current.value`
Помогите

```
let textInput = React.createRef;
let textOutput = React.createRef;

function GetName() {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

window.onload = function () {
    setShow(true);
};

function handleClose() {
    setShow(false);
}

function Input(event) {
    console.log(textInput.current.value)
}

return (
    <>
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>Enter name:</Col>
                        <Col>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                id="input"
                                onInput={Input}
                                ref={textInput}
                                defaultValue="Steve"
                                onFocus={(e) => {
                                    document.getElementById("input").style.backgroundColor =
                                        "yellow";
                                }}
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row ref={textOutput}></Row>
                </Container>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button
                    variant="success"
                    onClick={handleClose}
                    defaultValue={"Steve"}
                >
                    Save Changes
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    </>
);
}

export default class Hobbys extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <>
            <GetName></GetName>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>Name: </Col>
                    <Col id='output' ref={textOutput}></Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}
}
```

Выводит ошибку при в писании текста в `<input>`:

```
Hobbys.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at Input (Hobbys.js:20:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
```